# Removing empty nodes but keep nodes with image tags

Tags: xpath, domdocument

I am trying to remove all the empty nodes but the code also detects nodes with image tag as empty. I need the nodes with img tag to remain. Also I don't need nodes with whitespaces and other non printable characters. This is my current code:

```
$empties= $xpath->query('//*[not((*))]');
foreach($empties as $empty){
   $empty->parentNode->removeChild($empty);     
}
```

I need this to go:

```
<div class='blah'> </div>
```

and these to stay

```
<div class='blah'><img src='bla'/></div>
<div class='blah'>some text</div>
```

Comment: I don't see why `//*[not((*))]` would select `<div class='blah'><img src='bla'/></div>`, it however selects the `img` element itself as that is empty. So you will need to explain which elements you are interested in, e.g. only `//div[not(*)]` or `//*[not(self::img) and not(*)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, let's clear up the ambiguity by using a more comprehensive example:**

```
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2"/>
  <div id="d3" class='blah'><img src='bla'/></div>
  <div id="d4" class='blah'>some text</div>
  <div id="d5" class='blah'> </div>
  <div id="d6" class='blah'>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Then**

- `//*[not(*) and text()[not(normalize-space())]]`

  **says** 
  *select
  elements without child elements but with child text
  consisting of only whitespace.*

  For the above XML, it selects the `d5` and `d6` `divs`, **not** the `img`, and **not** the `d1` through `d4` `divs`.

Comment: The description of the XPath expression is not completely correct. It selects elements that have no child elements but do have child text consisting **only** of whitespace. The OP wants to "remove all the empty nodes," so the expression should be modified to also select nodes that have no text at all.

Comment: @LarsH: You are right that my explanation required repair.  Fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: @LarsH: I know the question has the words *remove all empty nodes,* but I interpreted that phrase by itself to be **overstating the intention**.  That's why I upvoted your answer and commented that your XPath is more literally correct than mine.  I inferred that elements such as `div[@id='d2']` in addition to the `img` element, actually should ***not*** be selected, even though empty, and documented the point with an example.

Comment: OK. I agree that the question as stated is unclear, and not entirely consistent.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you've fully specified which nodes you want to stay, but the following XPath is consistent with your stated needs:

```
//*[not(self::img) and not(*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]
```

(Building on Martin's comment.)
This will select for removal all elements that are not `<img>`, and have no element children, and have no direct text node children that contain more than just whitespace.

Comment: This is probably a more literally correct answer than mine, +1.